# AngularJS chart update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

Probably easy but I cant understand this ... Problem is that the pie chart is not going to be show updated content from data at POST query.

Predefined content are shown on the page.

markup :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12" id="pie-chart" ng-controller="ChartCtrlS">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Label 23 </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie chart-xs" data="pie2.data" labels="pie2.labels"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And controller code :

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
    .controller('ChartCtrlS', ['$scope','$http',  function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.pie2 = {
            labels : ["TheOne", "TheOne Next"],
            data : [1, 1]
        };

<---- CODE CUT -->

              }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                var slabels = [];
                var array = [];
                var sdata = [array];

                for (var i =0;  i < data.length; i++ ) {
                    var nom = data[i];
                    if (nom.seats > 0)  {
                        slabels.push(nom.name);
                        sdata.push (nom.seats);
                    }
                } 

                $scope.pie2.labels.push.apply(slabels);
                $scope.pie2.data.push.apply(sdata);
                $scope.vpresults = data;

            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

Angulajs version is 1.2.16, angulajs-chart 0.5.3

Comment: Ok found a solution     Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.pie2.labels, slabels);
                Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.pie2.data, sdata);
 will do the trick and force update chart correctly.